# Storing umlauts in lists/sets

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have words with special german characters (ÄÖÜäöüß) and want to iterate over the words letter by letters. Having those special characters creates problems because they are converted into two characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "ä"            # prints ä
print len(["ä"])     # prints 1
print len(list("ä")) # prints 2

s = set()
s.add("ä")
a = next(iter(s))

print s      # prints: set(['\xc3\xa4'])
print a      # prints: ä
print len(a) # prints: 2
```

What do I need to change to get always 1 as an answer, where now 2 is printed?

Comment: Store them as unicode characters. That solves the problem

Comment: I think if you use 3.x they will print as 1 length.  I tried your code in 3.4.3 and it worked fine.

Comment: Read this post: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky. And read the [UTF-8](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) article in Wikipedia.

Comment: @Ernesto The OP is not using Python 3 as you can tell from the usage of `print s`. In Python 3 this would be `print(s)`.

Comment: Strings and Unicode are handled fundamentally differently in python 3.x.

Comment: I know that.  Which is why I said "IF YOU USE 3.X" not "You are using 3.x so it should work"

Comment: Are you only needing to handle special characters literals in your Python script, or are you also reading them in from user input &/or files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this at the top of your python scrip (must be the first statement)

`from __future__ import unicode_literals`

This has the effect of implicitly applying the `u` prefix to all strings.

This is [not uncontroverisal](http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html) but it's my preference as part of good practice to avoid unicode issues.   You should also do as @Basil Bourque mentioned in comments, and read the article about unicode so you are well informed.   And, as well as unicode_literals, the [unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#1) is important to help avoid these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7, Unicode strings are handled like this:

```
>>> print "ä"
ä
>>> len("ä")
2
>>> print u"ä"
ä
>>> len(u"ä")
1
```

Use the `u` prefix for an Unicode string.